# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" When trying to map a getDoc() function from Firebase in Next.js

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, next.js

Hello fellow StackOverflow community,
I've encountred an error when trying to `.map()` a `getDoc()` constant in my Next.js app, saying the following: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')". I'm new to Next.js and I would appreciate a lot any kind of help from the community. I've been stuck on this error for a very long time trying to search for an answer on internet but nothing.

Here you can review the code of `[id].js`:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Head from "next/head";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";
import ChatScreen from "../components/ChatScreen";
import { db } from "../../firebase";
import { collection, doc, orderBy, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const Chat = () => {
  return (
    <Container className="bg-stone-900">
      <Head></Head>
      <Sidebar />
      <ChatContainer>
        <ChatScreen />
      </ChatContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Chat;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const ref = doc(collection(db, "chats"), context.query.id);
  const messagesRes = await getDoc(
    ref,
    collection(db, "messages"),
    orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
  );

  const messages = messagesRes.docs
    .map((doc) => ({ //Here is the error line.
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
    }))
    .map((messages) => ({
      ...messages,
      timestamp: messages.timestamp.toDate().getTime(),
    }));

  const chatRes = await getDoc();
  const chat = {
    id: chatRes.id,
    ...chatRes.data(),
  };

  return {
    props: {
      messages: JSON.stringify(messages),
      chat: chat,
    },
  };
}

const Container = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const ChatContainer = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: scrollbar;
`;
```

Again, thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be **getDocs** if you are trying to loop through the docs array,you cannot loop through using getDoc since it only returns a single document which is not an array, hence why you are getting undefined.

You can try the code below to loop through the messages using **getDocs**

```
const ref = doc(collection(db, "chats"), context.query.id);
  const messagesRes = await getDocs(
    ref,
    collection(db, "messages"),
    orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
  );
```

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks a lot, this did work! I wish you a great day.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is a nightmare for a lot of us starting out. I know I struggled with it as well. That said, the datasnapshot returns a json object. The .map() function is for arrays. Therefore it has to be manipulated so the map knows how to iterate through it.

Per w3

```
array.map(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue).
```

So your

```
data.map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(data)));
```